# Can I filter more than one list's items and show the result?

Tags: c#, list, text

I have 3 lists:

```
 - List 1: 1,2,3,4,5
 - List 2: 3,6,7,8,9,10
 - List 3: 5,8,11,12,13,14
```

and I have checkboxes respectively, so if a user clicks on checkbox 1 textbox will display list 1 and so on. the problem is all lists have some items that other ones also have them if a user clicks 2 checkboxes it should only display the ones that both lists have. How can I do it?

Comment: You need to write code for that and ask a question here is you face any specific issue in that. For hint , you need to learn about Intersect linq method  http://dotnetpattern.com/linq-intersect-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Intersect method from Linq:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> l2 = new List<int>() { 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; 
List<int> l3 = new List<int>() { 5, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14 };

var result = l1.Intersect(l2).ToList();
```

You also need a way how to determine which lists were chosen..

Comment: For determination I have check boxes, I applied your way, mechanism was true but the desired result would be for eg: if box 2 and 3 is checked it should give : 8 because it's the only number that is present in both lists. Thanks a lot for your help